# Warning: SQL injection attacks

Tags: c#, interop, fxcop

I have been trying to adapt my code to FxCop rules and I found this warning: CA2100 Review the query string passed to 'OleDbDataAdapter.OleDbDataAdapter(string, OleDbConnection)' in 'WavesShaperNew.Parse(string, int)' for possible SQL injection attacks. If the string is composed using any user input, consider using a stored procedure or a parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string concatenations.

I have searched in the [Microsoft Official Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2100?view=vs-2019) and similar questions, but still do not understand what this warning mean and how to solve it.

```
ComboBox sheets = new ComboBox();
TextBox startRange = new TextBox();
TextBox endRange = new TextBox();

string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM[" + sheets.SelectedItem + startRange.Text + ":" + endRange.Text + "]");
query = query.Replace("'", "");

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customers; delete from customers; blah blah blah` You just lost all your customers.... When you find yourself constructing parameters from user input and raw sql you just opened yourself to a world of hurt. The fix is to ***ALLWAYS*** use *parameterized queries*

Comment: [Or shown another way](https://i.chzbgr.com/full/7906458624/hEFCAF648/sql-injection)

Comment: @MichaelRandall The only problem here is that table names cannot be parameterised. The way to avoid SQL injection here would be to whitelist table names.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay and how would it be to whitelist table names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally parameterise all SQL queries to avoid [SQL injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15#validate-all-input) attacks, rather than using string concatenation / interpolation.

However, table names cannot be parameterised.

To avoid SQL injection here, you can whitelist your valid table names:

```
var queryableTables = new HashSet<string>
{
    "table1",
    "table2",
    // etc.
};

string tableName = sheets.SelectedItem + startRange.Text;

if (!queryableTables.Contains(tableName))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{tableName} is not queryable");
}

string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]");
```

Comment: This is not very effective. "table1; delete from table1;" is still valid input, because it _contains_ a valid table name.

Comment: @oerkelens No it isn't. `Contains` here is `HashSet<T>.Contains` not `string.Contains`. Your logic would apply to `queryableTables.Any(tableName.Contains)`.